# Argument `$color` of `darken($color, $amount)` must be a color Bootstrap 4 Angular 6

Tags: bootstrap-4, angular6

Attempting to use Bootstrap 4 a la carte in my Angular 6 app like so in my angular.json file...

```
"styles": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_functions.scss",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_variables.scss",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_mixins.scss",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ]
```

Which yields this error in the terminal after sass load attempt is made...

> ERROR in ./node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_variables.scss
>   (./node_modules/raw-loader!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib??embedded!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--15-3!./node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_variables.scss)
>   Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js):
>
> undefined
>                              ^
>         Argument `$color` of `darken($color, $amount)` must be a color

This is the line in question in _variables.scss: 
`$link-hover-color: darken($link-color, 15%) !default;`

Two lines above it's declared: 
`$link-color: theme-color("primary") !default;`

I've looked through many possible solutions on here but most of them say to put functions before vars which is already done yet the error still persists.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: what is `$color` 's value?

Comment: This is the line in question in _variables.scss:
`$link-hover-color:          darken($link-color, 15%) !default;`

Two lines above it's declared:
`$link-color:                theme-color("primary") !default;`

Comment: You should put the relevant parts of that file in your answer

Comment: Added those parts to my _question._

Comment: on the code you use variable `$link-color` whereas the error message cites `$color` - are you using the proper variables?

Answer (score 15):

I hit this issue. All that was required was to import functions before my other imports:

```
@import '../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions';
// ... remaining bootstrap imports...
```

Answer (score 9):

Can you move those imports into your `"src/styles.scss"` file?

```
// src/styles.scss

@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins";
```

Comment: I can. Not really the way I wanted to do it but this works and doesn't throw an error.

Answer (score 4):

In the new version, You have to import bootstrap variables as follows.

```
@import "~bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import '~bootstrap/scss/variables';
```

Answer (score -3):

You should import the bootstrap scss file from node_modules before importing variables in src/styles.scss file.

```
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss";
@import "variables";
```

Comment: that would be the wrong way around. variables first.